# iteration using for loop over createreadstream in node js using webdav downloads empty files

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to download some files from a SFCC WebDAV .I want to iterate over the files and write the files in my local machine,
If I don't loop the files and just read and write one file, it works fine.

Here  is the code snippet

```
let fs = require('fs');
let { createClient } = require("webdav");

let client = createClient(
        "https://../demandware.servlet/webdav/Sites/Logs",
        {
            username: "*",
            password: "*"
        }
    );
client
.getDirectoryContents("/")
.then(function(contents) {
    var directories = contents;
    for(var i =0; i< directories.length ; i++) {
        var  fileName = directories[i].filename;
        var filePath= String(fileName);
        let readStream = client.createReadStream(fileName);
        console.log(readStream);
        let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream("C:/Users/../Documents/COE/../logs/"+ fileName);
        readStream.pipe(writeStream);
    }

});
```

Comment: Where are you seeing empty files?  You don't have any events listening for when any of your streams are done so it seems likely that you're attempting to use the files BEFORE the streams have completed.  Note, you also have NO error handling of any kind so you would have no way of getting notified of errors in your streams.

Comment: Also, I suspect that `C:/Users/*/Documents/COE/*/logs/"` is probably an invalid path as I don't think you can have a `*` in a path name.

Comment: @jfriend00
What would you suggest in this case? The * is just to hide my url and folders
Also, I have posted my answer below through which I was able to achieve it. Let me know if you have any further suggestion.

Comment: I would suggest you show exactly where in your code you're trying to use these files you generate just like I asked in my first comment 2 days ago.  These will not be empty files unless you're trying to use them BEFORE they have been downloaded.

Comment: @jfriend00
What my requirement is to create a connection with Webdav. After a successful connection, I want to read all the log files and write them on my local machine.
the code  client.createReadStream(fileName); will read the content of the files on the webdav and the code readStream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("C:/Users/*/logs"+ fileName)) will write the files on my local machine. Since this is for multiple files, hence I used for loop.  The sign * is just to hide the exact path on stackoverflow, otherwise the path is full in my code.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to approach this.  If you want maximum speed and the webDav source will process more than one download at once, then you can read the files in parallel like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { pipeline } = require('stream/promises');
const { createClient } = require("webdav");

const client = createClient(
    "https://../demandware.servlet/webdav/Sites/Logs", {
        username: "*",
        password: "*"
    }
);
client.getDirectoryContents("/").then( function(directories) {
    const promises = directories.map(dir => {
        const fileName = dir.filename;
        const readStream = client.createReadStream(fileName);
        const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream("C:/Users/../Documents/COE/../logs/" + fileName);
        return pipeline(readStream, writeStream);
    });
    Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
        // all streams are done here
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
});
```

If, on the other hand, the webDav source can only handle one file download at a time, then you can sequence the downloads like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { pipeline } = require('stream/promises');
const { createClient } = require("webdav");

const client = createClient(
    "https://../demandware.servlet/webdav/Sites/Logs", {
        username: "*",
        password: "*"
    }
);
client.getDirectoryContents("/").then(async function(directories) {
    try {
        for (const dir of directories) {
            const fileName = dir.filename;
            const readStream = client.createReadStream(fileName);
            const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream("C:/Users/../Documents/COE/../logs/" + fileName);
            await pipeline(readStream, writeStream);
        }
        
        // all streams are done here
        
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi @jfriend00 , thanks for the response, but the other problem I have is the node version which is 13.9 whereas  require('stream/promises') was introduces in version 15.5
Can you help with some other method please.

Comment: @sonal - The pipeline function itself has been in the stream module since v10.0.  You can use `util.promisify()` on it to make a promise version that will work as above.  Example in [this article](https://youknowfordevs.com/2019/04/20/why-you-need-a-pipeline-runner-for-your-node-streams.html).

Answer (score -1):

Well, I was able to achieve this via below code

```js
let fs = require('fs');
let { createClient } = require("webdav");
let start = async () => {
    let client = createClient(
            "https://*/on/demandware.servlet/webdav/Sites/Logs",
            {
                username: "*",
                password: "*"
            }
        );
    let directories = await client
    .getDirectoryContents("/");
    let files =  await directories;
    //console.log(files);
    
    for(let i =0; i< files.length ; i++) {
    let  fileName = files[i].filename;
    if(fileName.includes('.log')){
        let readStream =  client.createReadStream(fileName);
        // wait for 5 seconds, then pipe
        setTimeout(function() {

          let writeStream = readStream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("C:/Users/*/logs"+ fileName));

          writeStream.on('finish', function() {
            console.log('all done!');
          });

          writeStream.on('error', function(err) {
            console.error(err);
          });

        }, 5000);
    }
    }
}

 

start();
```

Comment: `setTimeout()` is a hack and not the correct way to solve any problem like this as your code could easily break if the timing changes.  Also, it's unclear what problem the `setTimeout()` even bypasses either since ALL it does is delay each `pipe()` for 5 seconds.  I asked you a question in my first comment above that you did not answer.  Can't help you if you don't explain the actual problem so I can understand.